# google places api returns a string, how do I parse to JSON object?

Tags: firebase, google-places-api, google-cloud-functions

In a small webshop that I am trying to setup, I need to update the opening hours in the background with firebase functions and google place details when a user creates a shoppingcart.

I can succesfully sent a GET request with POSTMAN to retrieve the opening hours of a shop using the following instructions:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

But I cannot access the response from the GET request as I usually do with JSON responses.

I tried also:`response.result.opening_hours.json()`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
export const mapGooglePlaces = functions.database
.ref('/shopping-carts/{shoppingCartId}/shippingManner')
.onWrite(event => {
    const shippingManner = event.data.val();

    const optionsAPI = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY',
    };

    return request(optionsAPI)
        .then(response => {
            const openingHours = response.result.opening_hours;
            console.log(openingHours);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log(response.status);` to confirm a [result was returned](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsStatusCodes).

Comment: @BobSnyder, thank you for your support. If  I do this I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'opening_hours' of undefined
    at request.then.response (/user_code/lib/index.js:127:45)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is not a JSON object.  It is JSON formatted text and must be parsed to create an object.  Modify the code as follows:

```
return request(optionsAPI)
    .then(response => {
        const responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
        const openingHours = responseObject.result.opening_hours;
        console.log(openingHours);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Also, before using the `opening_hours` or any other property of `result`, you should test `responseObject.status === 'OK'` to [confirm that a place was found](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsStatusCodes) and at least one result was returned.